# Why is there not enough memory in the simplest loop and with an array of 3 elements?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is a function that displays categories ranging from the very top:

```
function getFullCategoryName($strCategoryId, $arrCategories)
{
    $strCategoryIdPaent = NULL;
    $arrCategoryCurr = isset($arrCategories[$strCategoryId]) ? $arrCategories[$strCategoryId] : NULL;
    $arrCategoriesNames = [];
    while (is_array($arrCategoryCurr)) {
        $arrCategoriesNames[] = $arrCategoryCurr['title'];
        if ($arrCategoryCurr['parentId'] && isset($arrCategories[$arrCategoryCurr['parentId']])) {
            $arrCategoryCurr = $arrCategories[$arrCategoryCurr['parentId']];
        } else {
            $arrCategoryCurr = NULL;
        }
    }
    krsort($arrCategoriesNames);
    return implode(' > ', $arrCategoriesNames);
}
```

With just 3 array elements, I get an error:

> "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"

I understand that I am using something wrong. Please, help me understand what exactly.

This is my input array:

```
$arrCategories = array (
    193450 => 
    array (
        'id' => '193450',
        'parentId' => '193450',
        'title' => 'Blood glucose meter',
    ),
    193451 => 
    array (
        'id' => '193451',
        'parentId' => '193450',
        'title' => 'Sugar test strips',
    ),
    193452 => 
    array (
        'id' => '193452',
        'parentId' => '193452',
        'title' => 'Blood glucose meter',
    ),
);
```

This is the call to the function:

```
$strCategoryId = 193450;
getFullCategoryName($strCategoryId, $arrCategories);
```

Comment: `else {
            $arrCategoryCurr = NULL;
        }` this part is not getting triggered

Comment: Maybe. But when I've changed NULL to string "NULL"
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9h6v-wu42
error is the same
E_ERROR : type 1 -- Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) -- at line 29

Comment: Changing `NULL` to a string is not the problem. The `else` condition is never entered, so `$arrCategoryCurr` is never set to `NULL` (or `'NULL'` or whatever), so `is_array($arrCategoryCurr)` indefinitely remains true, so the loop never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (sample) data has an issue based on my reading of your function.

The `parentId` and `index` are the same in some items. This would create an infinite loop based on what I can work out from the question.

A better structure would be something like the following, with some error checking in the loop:

```
function getFullCategoryName($strCategoryId, $arrCategories) {
    // set a base / default value
    $arrCategoriesNames = [];
    // do we even have anything to work with?
    if (isset($arrCategories[$strCategoryId])) {
        // at least one entry
        do {
            // get the title
            $arrCategoriesNames[] = $arrCategories[$strCategoryId]['title'];

            // get the next id and error check the data
            if ((isset($arrCategories[$strCategoryId]['parentId'])) && 
                ($strCategoryId != $arrCategories[$strCategoryId]['parentId'])) {
                // next index found and not the same
                $strCategoryId = $arrCategories[$strCategoryId]['parentId'];

            } else {
                // either no parentId or a parentId that matches the current 
                // index. If that is the case, go no further.
                $strCategoryId = false;
            }
            // you could add another error check if you like.
            // if (count($arrCategoriesNames) == count($arrCategories)) {
            //     // go no further as data has a loop
            //     $strCategoryId = false;
            // }
        } while($strCategoryId);

        // sort the data? why?
        krsort($arrCategoriesNames);
    }
    // return a string
    return implode(' > ', $arrCategoriesNames);
}
```

And testing you sample array;

```
$result = getFullCategoryName(193450,$arrCategories);
var_dump($result);
```

Returns the following:

```
string(19) "Blood glucose meter"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `while (is_array($arrCategoryCurr))` loop never ends as the `else` block of `$arrCategoryCurr = NULL;` is never called.

This happens because you have a loop where a node id **is the same as his parent id**. Look at your array:

```
....
'id' => '193450',
'parentId' => '193450',
...
```

To fix it modify the `if` statement to:

```
if ($arrCategoryCurr['parentId'] && $arrCategoryCurr['parentId'] != $arrCategoryCurr['id'] && isset($arrCategories[$arrCategoryCurr['parentId']])) {
```

Comment: Thank you @dWinder! I've changed my code the same way as you wrote!